# SUM all rows in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am pulling live data from a DB2 server, I am unable to SUM all rows within my query.
On, (HTQTY - HTQTYC) as OnHand, I am trying to SUM all the result for an item.
The item has 66 rows at a total of 8896 pcs. I would like to see the result as 1 row at 8896 pcs.

I have tried different SQL queries with no luck.

```
select

cjobh.dnname as Customer,
cjobh.dnjob as Job#,
cjobh.dnpart as Kit#,
cjobh.dnqtyr as KitQTY,
methdm.aqmtlp as Component,
methdm.aqqppc as Qty,
cjobh.dnord# as SO#,
cjobh.dnitm# as SOL,
cjobh.dnsdat as Ship_By,
cjobh.dnodat as Released_On,
cjobop.ehodes as Kind,
htbinl as Location,
(HTQTY - HTQTYC) as OnHand,
(DNQTYR*AQQPPC) as Needed


from CJOBH

left join methdm on aqpart = dnpart
left join cjobop on ehjob# = dnjob
left join seri on htpart = aqmtlp

where dnstat <> 'C'
and dnpart like '%KIT%'
and ehseq# = '100'
and ehlin# = '1'
and HTPLNT = 'GC'
and HTSTS = 'A'
```

[image]

Comment: What's the PK of the table `CJOBH`? Group by it, and aggregate columns from other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
with cte as (
<put your query here> 
)
SELECT  sum(OnHand)
FROM cte
```

Edit:

If you need to keeep the other columns try adding an additional column like this

```
, sum(HTQTY - HTQTYC) over ()
```

Because you had no group by specified an empty brackets after the OVER keyword is enough. You could also add an partition by clause within the brackets if you need addtional grouping

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, it works but I believe misinterpreted myself. I am looking for then entire result as with everything I have selected in the query.  Customer, JOB, KIT, Etc..

Comment: That is why you should clearly describe what you need. Check out my edits in my answer